# How to acces resources in Razor?

Tags: vb.net, razor

I wish to access my resource file values which is in `Resources > Global.rex` in a view .

I've seen things like

```
@Using  System.Resources

End Using
```

or

```
@Resources.Global.Title
```

But none seems to work, how can I do that ?

Comment: Are you using Vb, not C#?

Comment: I am using VB, Yes